# Angular 2 ERROR with show image

Tags: angular

I want to show a image in my code. The image has been saved in text format in my database. I convert the string of image in image with the following line code:

```
 <img [src]="'data:image/png;base64,'+zona?.fotografia">
```

I succeed to show the image in the page, but in the console there are the following errors:

```
WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value data:image/png;base64
GET unsafe:data:image/png;base64, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

If i have seen the possible solution for the warning, i didn't understand the other error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure your application that this is an safe url. So you can do it via
[DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) service. Inject it into your component and use `bypassSecurityTrustUrl` method.

```
this.fotografia= this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(`data:image/png;base64,${this.zona?.fotografia}`)
```

and use it in the `<img [src]="fotografia">`

Comment: I have followed your suggestion and there aren't error, but there is a new error:
GET http://localhost:4200/null 404 (Not Found)